# Getting list of agents in container in jade

Tags: java, pug, agents-jade

How can i get list of agents (their names like "da0@ip" etc.) in specified container in jade in java? I've looked and only thing i can find is a list of ALL agents in all containers. I'm not really into jade, it's just a school project so any advice would be helpful.

Comment: advice: read your textbook or go through your course nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use AMS agent that is to send the request to it and handle responce. Something like:

```
QueryAgentsOnLocation ca = new QueryAgentsOnLocation();
ca.setLocation(...); // here is the information about you ontainer
Action actExpr = new Action(myAgent.getAMS(), ca);

ACLMessage request = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.REQUEST);
request.addReceiver(myAgent.getAMS());
request.setOntology(JADEManagementOntology.getInstance().getName());
request.setLanguage(FIPANames.ContentLanguage.FIPA_SL);
request.setProtocol(FIPANames.InteractionProtocol.FIPA_REQUEST);
myAgent.getContentManager().fillContent(request, actExpr);
myAgent.send(request);
```